# Can I use my Schengen Visa legally to travel from Italy to Norway and back?

Tags: schengen-visas, italy, poland, norway, embassies

I am an Indian. At present (09/12/2022) I am in Florence, attending a Winter School. I have a single-entry visa issued by the Italian Embassy.

I requested for a 21 day long visa (28th Nov - 19th Dec) which has been successfully granted (My visa is valid upto 3rd Jan, 2023).

While presenting documents for my visa, I provided my hotel booking for the entire period **only in Italy**.

However, my class will abruptly end in 15th Dec due to some problem of the lecturer. So, before returning India, I was planning to travel to Tromso (Norway), and spend the remaining days before returning to Italy, to finally leave for India.

My questions are therefore as follows:-

1. Can I travel **legally** to Tromso with my Schengen Visa?
2. Given that I have mostly stayed in Italy, will it be a problem if I go for just 3 nights?
3. The flights between Italy and Tromso has a layover in Poland. While entering Poland, should this be a problem as well?
4. What are the documents I need besides Passport, Visa, Tromso hotel booking and Tromso to Italy return ticket?

Comment: Note that visas have both a validity and a duration. Make sure you respect both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I travel legally to Tromso with my Schengen Visa?

Yes.

> Given that I have mostly stayed in Italy, will it be a problem if I go for just 3 nights?

No.

> The flights between Italy and Tromso has a layover in Poland. While entering Poland, should this be a problem as well?

No.

> What are the documents I need besides Passport, Visa, Tromso hotel booking and Tromso to Italy return ticket?

You might want something to read on the plane.  Otherwise, nothing.